# Clear css cache on impresspage 4.1.0

Tags: caching, impresspages

I don't find how to clear css cache on ImpressPage 4.1.0.
There is no button in administator > system.

Help please.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is not fully implemented, yet. Cache is invalidated during updates or when theme options are changed (through admin interface).

Other option (more technical) is to change cache version number directly in the database. Open `ip_storage` table and search for `cacheVersion`. Increase value and everything should be ok.